# Why is div element's css property not applied to its child anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, anchor

When I try to put an anchor inside div element, the div elements css are not applied to anchor. Below is the code:

```css
.nav-sub-menu-item {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-sub-menu-item">
  <a href="#">sub-menu-1</a>
</div>
```

The anchor stays with blue color font with underline though I have set the text-decoration & color properties. Shouldn't the child inherit the parent's css class' properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't be inherited to `<a />`.

If you want to make `<a />` be inherited, you should declare it.

```css
.nav-sub-menu-item {
    background-color: gainsboro;    
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-sub-menu-item > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-sub-menu-item">
     <a href="#">sub-menu-1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
.nav-sub-menu-item a {
    background-color: gainsboro;    
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, certain properties are inheritable and others are not. This is defined in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance). Every CSS property has the *inherited* property which can be referred to see whether its supports default inheritance or not.

> CSS properties can be categorized in two types:
>
> - inherited properties, which by default are set to the computed value of the parent element
> - non-inherited properties, which by default are set to initial value of the property

In your case, the `text-decoration` property doesn't support default inheritance, refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) to learn more.

In cases where default, inheritance is not supported the element gets the initial value of that property. However, you can force inheritance by using the `inherit` keyword which explicitly applies inheritance.

> When no value for a non-inherited property has been specified on an element, the element gets the initial value of that property (as specified in the property's summary).

Also, by default, `a` (anchor) tags does not inherit properties like color if an href attribute is present. This is explained in this [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2)

Usually, the contents of A are not rendered in any special way when A defines an anchor only.

> User agents generally render links in such a way as to make them obvious to users (underlining, reverse video, etc.). The exact rendering depends on the user agent. Rendering may vary according to whether the user has already visited the link or not.

.....

> Usually, the contents of A are not rendered in any special way when A defines an anchor only.

This inheritance can be achieved through applying the following code to your CSS:

```
.nav-sub-menu-item > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```